# javascript IsNaN and 0

Tags: javascript, nan, zero

I have some code that's returning unexpected results.

HTML:

```
<select name="cc_dropdown[0]" id="cc-dropdown-0" style="display: none;">
    <option value="">Select a card</option>
    <option value="0" selected="selected">***********8431</option>
    <option value="-1">Use a new card</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var ccVal = parseInt($("#cc-dropdown-0 option:selected").val());
var errors = [];

if( ccVal == -1 ) {
        if( $('#cc_number-'+bIdx).val().length <= 0 || !isValidCreditCardNo($('#cc_number-'+bIdx).val()) ) {
            errors.push('Invalid Credit card Number');
        }

        if( $('#cc_name-'+bIdx).val().length <= 0 ) {
            errors.push('Please provide the name on the credit card.');
        }

        if($('#cc_exp_month-'+bIdx).val() == ""){
            errors.push('Please Select an Expiration Date.');
        }

        if($('#cc_exp_year-'+bIdx).val() == ""){
            errors.push('Please Select an Expiration Date.');
        }

        if( !isValidZipcode($('#cc_zip-'+bIdx).val())){
            errors.push('Please enter a valid zipcode.');
        }
    }    else if ( ccVal == 'na' || ccVal == '' || isNaN(ccVal)) {
        console.log("ccVal inside else if: " + ccVal);
        console.log("ccVal type: " + typeof ccVal);
        errors.push('Please select a credit card, or enter a new one.')
    }
else {
    console.log("else");
    errors.push("Arg!");
}
console.dir(errors);
```

In this case, `ccVal` is 0, and yet it's falling into the else if statement. I would expect that to happen only if it's not a number at all. Expected result is that it should fall into the final `else` statement. Here's a JSFiddle with the results: http://jsfiddle.net/n2Uy7/

Can anyone explain why this would be the case? If it's 0, it should not hit either the `if` or the `else if` statements. Does JS consider 0 to be NaN, even though `typeof` indicates that it is a number?

Comment: First off, you should NEVER use `parseInt()` without passing the radix parameter.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I wasn't aware of that; I don't recall that being an issue the last time I used the function (somewhere around 1997...) So for standard numbering, do I use 10 for base 10?

Comment: Yes, use `10`. The reason is that without that second parameter for the radix if there is a leading zero or leading `0x` in the string to be parsed `parseInt()` may treat it as octal or hexadecimal. I say "may" because it depends on the browser and whether you're in strict mode. (And of course for user-entered data the user may enter a leading 0, however unlikely that may seem - not a problem for your hardcoded select values, but still it's good to get in the habit of always supplying the radix.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`0 == ''` is `true` so the `isNaN` part doesn't even get evaluated.

Use `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware that 0 was considered to be equal to an empty string.

Comment: `==` does some type coercion. `===` doesn't. MDN gives a [more detailed explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing with "just" double equals signs, so `0 == ''` (try it in your browser's console).

One way to fix the issue is to use triple equals instead. Another way is to remove the `parseInt` entirely, so `ccVal` will remain a string. String to string comparisons will then behave as expected (`'' != '0'`).

Removing the `parseInt` would also solve another issue (you are not passing in the radix, but you *must*). Why is it there anyway?